# Cardinality of set of normal functions $f \colon \omega_{\alpha} \to \omega_{\alpha}$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

What is the cardinality of the set of all [normal functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_function) $f \colon \omega_{\alpha} \to \omega_{\alpha}$, where $\omega_{\alpha}$ is the initial ordinal of $\aleph_{\alpha}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81850/cardinality-of-cofinal-set-of-normal-functions-f-colon-omega-1-to-omega-1/81865).